# Very simple, shared to-do list

Tags: web-apps

I'm looking for a very simple to-do list that can be shared with Android and Windows (ie just web access). I only require a list with text that I can edit; I don't need 'set dates' and 'categories' etc.

I'm now using a text file in my Dropbox account, which meets the requirements, but I'd like to have a dedicated app to open this. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not using Windows, so I cannot really recommend anything from my experience. But you might wish to check with my Android-App-List for [Todo Lists](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_todo).

Comment: you could keep going with your text file but switch dropbox to **[botsync](http://botsync.com/)** for android and follow the homapage's one-time instructions for windows.

Comment: Did you see the [comparison of note-taking software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_notetaking_software) on Wikipedia?

Answer (score 2):

**Google Keep** is simple app for notes and todo lists. It is a free Android app - [Google Keep on Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.keep).

It lets you store text notes, or lists with checkboxes. You can add a photo to a note or list. You can also set reminders for a date/time, and colour code notes.
[image: Google Keep screenshot, on Android]

It is synced to a Google account, but it is somewhat separate to Gmail or Google Calendar. You can use it online at [keep.google.com](https://keep.google.com/). There is also an app for the Chrome browser.

Answer (score 1):

Google Calendar can have a very simple TODO list called "Tasks" on the right of the screen:

[image]

You can:

- Add/edit/delete a task
- Drag a task higher or lower in the list

The drawback is that you get a calendar on the left side, but you don't have to use it.

On Android I use the [GTasks](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.dayup.gtask&hl=en) free app to sync the list. It has a widget which shows the top of your tasks list, tap it to add a new task.

Free.

Comment: But how do you use it on Android? It doesn't seem to be available through the Google Calendar app.

Comment: You're right! I just added a paragraph about Android.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Evernote](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.evernote) to keep track of my todo list. It is cross platform, and it has a [chrome app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/evernote-web/lbfehkoinhhcknnbdgnnmjhiladcgbol?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) for easy web access.

From the description page, you can find what you've requested under key features:

- Create and edit text notes, to-dos and task lists
- Save, sync and share files

Answer (score 1):

If you only need web, use the Free version of [Wunderlist](https://www.wunderlist.com/). Very simple interface (a plus on a small phone screen).

This is the *most complex* (task properties) screen it has:  ;-)

[image]
(annotated in English)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to keep your text file but replace dropbox with [botsync](http://botsync.com/)

botsync should synchronize your text file with your windows machine.

[image: botsync 1] [image: botsync 2]
<sup>*botsync* (click images for larger variants)</sup>

on the windows machine, you could follow the one-time instructions from botsync's homapage:

> Using BotSync with Windows
>
> BotSync is designed for Linux/BSD/OSX servers, however, it can work
>   with Windows using [cygwin opensshd](http://www.cygwin.com/):

```
1. Download and install cygwin from the link above. Enable Net -> opensshd
2. Click the cygwin desktop icon, then run:
   ssh-host-config -y
   net start sshd
   mkpasswd -l -u botsync >> /etc/passwd
   passwd botsync
    [enter a password]
3. Open BotSync's Config and set the hostname.
    Set username to 'botsync'. Set Remote Dir to '/home/botsync'
    This maps to c:\cygwin\home\botsync\ on the Windows filesystem.
    To use another Windows directory, first, convert it to a cygwin
    path for BotSync's Remote Dir.
Ex: D:\Media\Music\ becomes /cygdrive/d/Media/Music
4. Open TCP Port 22 in the Windows firewall, and enable port forwarding
    on your router, if necessary.
5. Start BotSync!
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [Trello](http://trello.com).  I think it's quite reliable, fast and sync's with all my devices.

Comment: Trello does have some extra functions that OP doesn't request, but in my opinion they are not bloating the interface, so I think Trello would be a great choice. It's seems quite CPU heavy though.

Answer (score 0):

### OneNote

- There is (among others) an Android app, a website.
- You can create simple todo lists with checkboxes, which synchronize across all your devices.

You need a Microsoft account, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I use the free version of [Evernote](http://evernote.com/) for this.

A simple text file containing a list of to-do items is a fraction of Evernote's capabilities, but it does just what I require.